# What are these seeds in papery pink casing?

Tags: identification, seeds

I found these seeds all over my yard which I think were dropped by some nesting starlings. Each seed has a dry, papery pink casing. The attached photos show the seed inside the casing on the left, with the peeled seed on the right. First photo shows topside of peeled seed, second shows underside of peeled seed. Size comparison is to a Canadian dime (coin is about 18mm diameter). Any ideas what they might be?

[image: topside of peeled seed]
[image: underside of peeled seed]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you will find a mature English Ivy plant (Hedera helix) nearby. I've found dozens of the same seeds on the ground under my plum tree this week (Jan 30, 2013). I found your post while trying to determine the source. Today I went on safari and found the source in another yard. Apparently the mature vine looks different from the younger vines, I had thought they were two different plants. The birds are going crazy for the berries but they don't seem to eat the seeds, only the skins. My guess is you also have lots of purple bird droppings in the same area as the pink seed pods.